# Autolayout in Xcode and keep aspect ratio

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

I have some trouble with the layout-system in xcode.

Is there a way to accomplish this:

- Keep clearance of **8 units** between the "Add/Edit Image from Camera", the left side of the Image View and the right side of the Image View if you have enough space at the bottom to keep the aspect ratio of 1/1.
- And if you don't have enough space at the bottom keep 8 units from the bottom and 8 units from the "Add/Edit Image from Camera", center it and keep an aspect ratio of 1/1.

I want to use as much area as possible without distorting the image.

This is the closest I can get. I know the iPhone 3.5" isn't that common anymore but I still want to find a proper solution for this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might just need to change your leading and trailing constraints on the UIImageView to >=8 rather than =8. Set a center.X alignment on the UIImageView too.

Then your 1/1 proportions will dictate that the height of the UIImageView will reduce until it can all fit on the screen.

Comment: You are awesome! That was the hint I was looking for. Somehow the priority for the bottom constraints messed up the layout as well. Setting it to 750 solved that too.

Comment: Excellent. Really glad to hear it helped.